# Set trigger to border background inside tree view Hierarchical Data Template on isSelected property

Tags: wpf, xaml, triggers, treeview

```
<TreeView Margin="0,0,0,49.8" x:Name="lstOwnActions" ItemsSource="{Binding ActivityList}" TreeViewItem.Expanded="lstOwnActions_Expanded"
                      HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" >
                <TreeView.Resources>
                    <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:ActivityList}" ItemsSource="{Binding SubCategory}">
                        <Border CornerRadius="10" Background="Black" Width="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" ToolTip="{Binding Name}" PreviewMouseDown="TextBlock_PreviewMouseDown" >
                            <Label Content="{Binding Name}" Foreground="White" Width="Auto" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" />
                        </Border>
                    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
                    <HierarchicalDataTemplate  DataType="{x:Type local:SubCategory}">
                        <Border CornerRadius="10" Background="Black" Width="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Top" ToolTip="{Binding SubCategoryName}" PreviewMouseDown="TextBlock_PreviewMouseDown">
                            <Label  Foreground="White" Content="{Binding SubCategoryName}" Width="Auto" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
                        </Border>
                    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
                </TreeView.Resources>
            </TreeView>
```

I have this default xaml with tree view.

I want to Change the color of background to Red when tree view item is selected by triggers.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `Style` with a `DataTrigger`:

```
<TreeView Margin="0,0,0,49.8" x:Name="lstOwnActions" ItemsSource="{Binding ActivityList}" TreeViewItem.Expanded="lstOwnActions_Expanded"
          HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" >
    <TreeView.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="borderStyle" TargetType="Border">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Black" />
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=TreeViewItem}}"
                             Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:ActivityList}" ItemsSource="{Binding SubCategory}">
            <Border CornerRadius="10" Style="{StaticResource borderStyle}" Width="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" ToolTip="{Binding Name}" PreviewMouseDown="TextBlock_PreviewMouseDown" >
                <Label Content="{Binding Name}" Foreground="White" Width="Auto" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" />
            </Border>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate  DataType="{x:Type local:SubCategory}">
            <Border CornerRadius="10" Style="{StaticResource borderStyle}" Width="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Top" ToolTip="{Binding SubCategoryName}" PreviewMouseDown="TextBlock_PreviewMouseDown">
                <Label Foreground="White" Content="{Binding SubCategoryName}" Width="Auto" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
            </Border>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </TreeView.Resources>
</TreeView>
```

Comment: Thanks, mm8 for the reply, it's working great. But when subcategories are selected then there is a slight delay, can you suggest something for that?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by delay. There is nothing in the `Style` I posted that causes this delay anyway. Please ask a new question if you have another issue and/or please include a minimal reproducible sample of your issue.